# Oracle SQL Transpose data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have a requirement where i have data coming from tables like this

```
country  total_population  number_of_cities  number_of_airports
US        1,000,000,000          500                25
UK        2,000,000,000          400                20
```

This is dynamic data. The result i need to show as this

```
                         US              UK
total_population    1,000,000,000       2,000,000,000
number_of_cities       500               400
number_of_airports      25                20
```

How can I achieve this ?
Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of questions with answers for `[oracle]+[pivot]`. You know the key words, why not check out some of [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+pivot)???

Comment: This is not exact duplicate. My requirement is different from plain pivot. The question was to basically swap rows with columns. Found my answer after trying many times. The solution involves unpivoting first and then pivoting it back.

Comment: Okay. I have re-opened the question, so you can post your solution as an answer, should you feel like doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the requirement. It basically needed to swap the rows and columns. This can be achived by first unpivoting and then pivoting it back. Here is the query

```
select *
from (
    select 
        country,
          total_population, number_of_cities, number_of_airports
      FROM yourtable 
      ) unpivot ( val for stats in (total_population, number_of_cities, number_of_airports))
    pivot (sum(val) for country in ('US', 'UK'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `MAX`, `CASE` and `UNION ALL`.

```
 SELECT 'total_population' metric,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'US' THEN total_population
           END)           US,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'UK' THEN total_population
           END)           UK
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'number_of_cities' metric,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'US' THEN number_of_cities
           END)           US,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'UK' THEN number_of_cities
           END)           UK
FROM   yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'number_of_airports' metric,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'US' THEN number_of_airports
           END)             US,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN country = 'UK' THEN number_of_airports
           END)             UK
FROM   yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2fbc5/4)

Comment: And when there are three countries in play? That's a lot of typing. The PIVOT operator is easier to maintain and (arguably) easier to understand.